# Which Selenium standalone version is compatible with Firefox version 58.0

Tags: selenium

Which Selenium standalone jars are compatible with Firefox version 58.0?I tried 2.46.0 selenium jars and I am getting this exception:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:

```
Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'CHDSEZ400598D', ip: '10.152.107.68', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
```

Answer (score 1):

*Mozilla Firefox Browsers* are released as **GA (General Availability)** versions irrespective of *Manual* or *Automation* testing. It's the *GeckoDriver* which controls the *Mozilla Firefox Browser* through *Marionette*. Again its the *Selenium Client* which initializes the *GeckoDriver*. So the **compatibility** rests partially with *Selenium Client* and partialy with *GeckoDriver*.

Though *Selenium* releases are made with outmost effort to keep the *Selenium Clients* backward compatible with the previous releases of *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox Browser* releases but the last dependency announced as per the *Selenium Release Notes* is as follows :

```
v3.4.0
======

* Geckodriver 0.16 is strongly recommended
```

The last announced dependency of *GeckoDriver 0.19.0 (2017-09-16)* is as follows :

```
0.19.0 (2017-09-16)
Note that with geckodriver 0.19.0 the following versions are recommended: - Firefox 55.0 (and greater) - Selenium 3.5 (and greater)
```

### Solution

An effective solution would be as follows :

- Update your *JDK* version to the latest version, currently [**vJDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html)
- Update your *Selenium Client* version to the latest version, currently [**v3.10.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)
- Update your *GeckoDriver* version to [**v0.19.1 (2017-10-30)**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
- Update your *Firefox Quantum Browser* version to [**v58.0.2**]
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [***CCleaner***](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Firefox* version is too old, then uninstall it through [***Revo Uninstaller***](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Firefox*.
- Execute your `@Test`.