# Which Selenium standalone version is compatible with Firefox version ESR 52.6.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Which Selenium standalone version is compatible with Firefox version ESR 52.6.0 and which gecko driver will support required jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Selenium standalone version is compatible with Firefox version 58.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144237/which-selenium-standalone-version-is-compatible-with-firefox-version-58-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Firefox` `52` or newer, `Selenium 3.4.0` will do. Gecko diver required is `gecko driver v0.16.0`. You can download it from [Gecko Driver Download](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Also you need to set the `System Property` for your program.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH\\TO\\YOUR\\geckodriver.exe");`