# Where to find the compatible version for selenium-server, geckodriver and firefox?

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I'm making some test with different version of Firefox.

Is there a matrix of something like that where I can find which version of selenium-server and geckodriver work with a specific version of firefox browers.

I'm interested in Firefox 52 and later.

In general is there a place in documentation with the good combinaison. Not only for firefox 58.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Selenium standalone version is compatible with Firefox version 58.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144237/which-selenium-standalone-version-is-compatible-with-firefox-version-58-0)

Comment: My question if more general and not duplicate your's that is specific to firefox 58.0

Comment: This QA might be of your help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453