# Browser compatibility with selenium for testing forms

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium3

I want to test forms quickly and reliably. I thought selenium-ide would be the answer but was put off by the fact that newer versions of firefox do not support the selenium-ide plugin. Would other selenium products such as selenium3 enable me to test forms in up to date versions of firefox (eg 57.01)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Selenium standalone version is compatible with Firefox version 58.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144237/which-selenium-standalone-version-is-compatible-with-firefox-version-58-0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here you can see Selenium 3 compatiblity with FF :

```
Firefox 38 and lower, use Selenium 2.46.0
Firefox < 47, use Selenium 2.53.1
Firefox >= 47, use Selenium 3.0.1 or later
```